# Let $f : X\rightarrow Y$ and $C, D \subseteq Y$. Fill and prove formulas.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Definition:
Let $f: A\rightarrow B$ be function and $X\subseteq A$.
The image of set X is defined as a set $f[X] = \{b\in B \:|\: \exists a\in X: f(a) = b\}$. Inverse image of set $Y\subseteq B$ is defined as $f^{-1} = \{a\in A\:|\:f(a)\in Y\}$.

Let $f : X\rightarrow Y$ and $C, D \subseteq Y$. Fill and prove formulas:
$$f[f^{-1}[C]] \: ? \: C$$
$$f[f^{-1}[C]]  = \: ?$$

I have read few articles about functions, images and inverse images and found that these two formulas should probably be written the following way:
$$f[f^{-1}[C]] \subseteq C \text{ for all functions}$$ 
$$f[f^{-1}[C]] = C \text{ for surjective (onto) functions}$$
I could not find any proofs of them and it is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition $x\in f^{-1}(C)\implies f(x)\in C$.  Thus $f(f^{-1}(C))\subseteq C$.

Now if $f$ is surjective,  then for each $c\in C$, $f^{-1}(c)\not=\emptyset$.  Hence $f(f^{-1})(c)=c$.  So $f(f^{-1})(C)=f(f^{-1})(\bigcup_{c\in C}c)=f(\bigcup_{c\in C}f^{-1}(c))=\bigcup_{c\in C} f(f^{-1})(c)=\bigcup_{c\in C}c=C$.